# Rust code refactor. Need better way to fix borrowing error

Tags: rust, refactoring, clone

I'm trying to write some filter to getting values from database. I have already fixed all occurring problems. But two thinks looks ugly.

In my opinion, in this case copying all Vector is not necessary. How can I do it better?

I add some comments in text for better understand.
My big function:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct DataTest {
    pub title: String,
    pub id: i32,
    pub chapter_id: i32,
}

impl DataTest {
    pub fn new(title: String, id: i32, chapter_id: i32) -> Self {
        let data_test = DataTest {
            title,
            id,
            chapter_id,
        };
        data_test
    }
}
fn main() {
    // Important notes! This data is faked! In real my example I'm getting much more complicated data.
    // I'm using gere left join from diesel to select specific fields from database. 
    let first = DataTest::new("Title".to_string(),
                                        2, 3);
    let second = DataTest::new("Title".to_string(),
                                        2, 8);
    let third = DataTest::new("Title".to_string(),
                                        2, 20);
    let fourth = DataTest::new("Strange title".to_string(),
                                        4, 6);
    
    let fifth = DataTest::new("Funny title".to_string(),
                                       12, 14);
    let sixth = DataTest::new("Funny title".to_string(),
                                        12, 21);
    let seventh = DataTest::new("Funny title".to_string(),
                                        12, 22);

    let eighth = DataTest::new("Great book bro!".to_string(),
                                        16, 25);
    let ninth = DataTest::new("Great book bro!".to_string(),
                                         16, 26);
    let tenth = DataTest::new("Great book bro!".to_string(),
                                         16, 29);

    // vector is faked data to simulate my example.
    let mut vector: Vec<DataTest> = vec![first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth, ninth, tenth];

    println!("Before job Vector: {:?}", &vector);
    
    // Here I want to filter data occuring more then once.
    // I'm grouping data to separated vectors for easier further processing.
    let mut ready: Vec<Vec<&DataTest>> = Vec::new();
    let mut previous_title = &String::new();
    let mut search = true;
        
    // Here is the first problem. I have to clone all vector!
    // I think it can be done without cloning.
    // I have mutable value, but here I'm just searching through vector.
    let test = vector.clone();
    for item in vector.iter() {
         if &item.title != previous_title { search = true }
             if &item.title == previous_title && search{
                 let result = test.iter()
                                  .filter(|x| x.title == item.title)
                                  .collect();
                 ready.push(result);
                 search = false;
             }
             previous_title = &item.title;
        }
        // Here I have grouped vector.
    println!("Ready Vector:\n{:?}", &ready);

    // Here I'm trying to search for each object the last chapter id.
    // After that I'm removing from vector older entries.
    for item in ready.iter() {
        let mut item_iter = item.iter();
        // Defining empty object
        let mut previous_data = &DataTest::new(
            "".to_string(),
            0,
            0,
        );
        loop {
            match item_iter.next() {
                Some(value) => {
                    if previous_data.title == value.title {
                        vector.remove(vector
                            .iter()
                            .position(|x| x.id == value.id)
                            .unwrap());
                    }
                    previous_data = value;
                        
                },
                None => break,
            }
        }
            
    }    
}
```

In the copy example I'm getting nice error:

```
cannot borrow `vector` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:74:29
   |
54 |                    let result = vector.iter()
   |                                 ------------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
63 |           for item in ready.iter() {
   |                       ------------ immutable borrow later used here
...
74 | /                             vector.remove(vector
75 | |                                 .iter()
76 | |                                 .position(|x| x.id == value.id)
77 | |                                 .unwrap());
   | |__________________________________________^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

I know what it means, and I already fixed it. But I think in not good way.

Second think is refactor problem but close related to previous one. In my opinion this function is too big and complicated. So I decided split it to two more. One more for each for loop.

And here are occurred more problem and completely destroy my code. I don't understand how can i do that?
I don't want copy all exceptions during splitting function, because there are many different errors and copying errors will make wall of text.

Edited part:
So I decided to placed here more example of data related to real tables:
My models:

```
#[derive(Associations, Identifiable, Queryable,
         PartialEq, Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[diesel(belongs_to(User))]
#[diesel(table_name = books)]
pub struct Book {
    pub id: i32,
    pub user_id: i32,
    pub title: String,
    pub book_description: String,
    pub normalize_book_title: String,    
    pub book_image: Option<String>,
    pub publish_day: chrono::NaiveDateTime,
}
#[derive(Associations, Identifiable, Queryable,
         PartialEq, Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[diesel(belongs_to(Book))]
#[diesel(table_name = book_chapters)]
pub struct BookChapter {
    pub id: i32,
    pub book_id: i32,
    pub title: String,
    pub normalize_title: String,
    pub body: String,
    pub description: String,
    pub publish_day: chrono::NaiveDateTime,
}

// I mapping results from database to structure
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct ListBookData {    
    pub book_title: String,
    pub book_image: Option<String>,
    pub book_description: String,
    pub normalize_book_title: String,
    pub chapter_title: Option<String>,
    pub chapter_description: Option<String>,
    pub chapter_id: Option<i32>,
    pub book_id: i32,
}
impl ListBookData {
pub fn new(book_title: String, book_image: Option<String>,
               book_description: String, normalize_book_title: String,
               chapter_title: Option<String>, chapter_description: Option<String>,
               chapter_id: Option<i32>, book_id: i32) -> Self {
                ListBookData {
                    book_title,
                    book_image,
                    book_description,
                    normalize_book_title,
                    chapter_title,
                    chapter_description,
                    chapter_id,
                    book_id,
                }
               }
}
// My query
pub fn my_query(db_connection: &mut PgConnection) -> Result<Vec<ListBookData>,
                                                                                            DieselError> {
        let result = books::table.left_join(book_chapters::table)
                    .select((book::title,
                             book::book_image,
                             book::book_description,
                             book::normalize_book_title,
                             chapter::title.nullable(),
                             chapter::description.nullable(),
                             chapter::id.nullable(),
                             book::id))
                    .order_by(book::title)
                    .load(db_connection);
}
// Data examples
let first = ListBookData::new(
                "First book title".to_string(),
                Some("path_to_image".to_string()),
                "Book description".to_string(),
                "first_book_title".to_string(),
                Some("First chapter title".to_string()),
                Some("Chapter description".to_string()),
                Some(1),
                1);
let second = ListBookData::new(
                "Second book title".to_string(),
                None,
                "Second Book description".to_string(),
                "second_book_title".to_string(),
                None,
                None,
                None,
                2);

let third = ListBookData::new(
                "Third book title".to_string(),
                Some("path_to_image".to_string()),
                "Third description".to_string(),
                "third_book_title".to_string(),
                Some("First chapter of the Third book title".to_string()),
                Some("Chapter description".to_string()),
                Some(3),
                3);
let fourth = ListBookData::new(
                "Fourth book title".to_string(),
                None),
                "Fourth description".to_string(),
                "fourth_book_title".to_string(),
                Some("Second chapter of the Third book title".to_string()),
                Some("Chapter description".to_string()),
                Some(4),
                3);

let fifth = ListBookData::new(
                "Fifth book title".to_string(),
                Some("path_to_image".to_string()),
                "Fifth description".to_string(),
                "fifth_book_title".to_string(),
                Some("Third chapter of the Third book title".to_string()),
                Some("Chapter description".to_string()),
                Some(5),
                3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for ansking a question, hopefully I can help point you in the right direction!

First off I will calrify the question I believe you are asking which is, "How can I idiomatically filter my data in Rust?"

For simplicity, the data you have provided is returned by `fake_data()`.

Currently the standard library does not have exactly what you are looking for but the `itertools` crate can fill this gap with the following...

```rust
let my_data = fake_data();
println!("Before job Vector: {:?}", &my_data);

let filtered: Vec<&DataTest> = my_data
    .iter()
    .group_by(|&x| x.title.clone())
    // Get the entry with the max chapter_id
    // Filter out empty optionals
    .into_iter()
    .filter_map(|(_key, data_group)| data_group.into_iter().max_by_key(|data| data.chapter_id))
    .collect();

println!("Ready Vector:\n{:?}", &filtered);
```

In the future should [`group_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.group_by) be stablized in the Rust standard library the following code could be used...

```rust
let my_data = fake_data();
println!("Before job Vector: {:?}", &my_data);

// Last Chapter ID for each title.
let filtered: Vec<&DataTest> = my_data
    // Put common titles into a group
    .group_by(|left, right| left.title == right.title)
    // Get the entry with the max chapter_id
    .map(|data_group| data_group.iter().max_by_key(|data| data.chapter_id))
    // Filter out empty optionals
    .filter_map(|x| x)
    .collect();

println!("Ready Vector:\n{:?}", &filtered);
```

In Rust iterators are super powerful tools that help you avoid many borrow checker woes.

Outside of manipulating data in Rust it could be that this challenge could be solved with SQL (or in this case Diesel) by performing filtering at the Database layer. This will likely provide much greater performance as this is what databases are built to do, and will cause fewer Rust related headaches.

An example SQL query and dataset [can be found here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2fe6eb/4/0).

Just to give you some idea of the kind of SQL features you may be interested, I have copied the query below.

```sql
SELECT id, MAX(chapter_id), title FROM data_test
  GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your time. I have a problem with better query because I have left join for two tables and main filter filed can be NULL. So If I have one raw then book have one or NONE chapter.
So Max is wrong way. But your example is great.
group_by will be great option! Such clean the code :)

Comment: If you have any example data for the two tables and what you are hoping to get out so I could give you some suggestions, otherwise good luck with your project!

Comment: I have already updated my post :)